# Monitor HashMap update using thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

What is the best way to monitor an update in a data-structure in Java using Java Threads? I will be creating a thread just by implementing a Runnable interface. That thread needs to sleep and wake up every 10 minutes and check to see if the HashMap is updated. What is the best way of doing this in Java?
Any help, much appreciated

Comment: This looks terribly like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sounds a bit gnarly, perhaps you could consider some sort of wrapper class for the HashMap that fires a changeEvent when the map is updated. Then anything that might be listening for that event can react accordingly.

Comment: @Ordous - I believe the word *is* would do better than *looks terribly like* :P

Comment: So, what I basically have is a HashMap (or ConcurrentHashmap for that matter) that is updated every once in a while. I want to be able to create a thread that wakes up every 10 minutes and checks to see if the HashMap has a new entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ScheduledExecutorService daemon = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
daemon.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyRunnable(myMapToCheck), 
                              10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTE);
//...
private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Map<K, V> lastState;
    private final Map<K, V> map;

    public MyRunnable(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.lastState = new HashMap<>(map);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // copy to avoid changes before updating lastState
        Map<K, V> currentState = new HashMap<>(map);
        if(currentState.equals(lastState)) {
            System.our.println("No change");
        } else {
            System.our.println("Change!");
        }
        lastState.clear();
        lastState.putAll(currentState);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the guarantee that the changes done (elements added) will be visible in to this thread?. How will this ensure *happens before* ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want a TimerTask to check if the map's been updated every 10 minutes.

```
private Map map = new HashMap();
private Map lastMapState = new HashMap(map);
private boolean updated = false;

//....

private void startCheckingUpdates() {

    // Timers run their tasks in a separate Thread
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        checkUpdated();
        }
    }, 600_000, 600_000);
}

//....

private boolean checkUpdated() {
    updated = !map.equals(lastMapState);
    lastMapState.clear();
    lastMapState.putAll(map);
    return updated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class to wrap your data-structure in, when modify operations come through your wrapper update a `lastModified` field. When your thread wakes up just check the `lastModified` field to see if you need to do something.

something like this:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ModTimeMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    private Date lastModified;

    public Date getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        updateLastModified();
        super.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K arg0, V arg1) {
        updateLastModified();
        return super.put(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> arg0) {
        updateLastModified();
        super.putAll(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object arg0) {
        updateLastModified();
        return super.remove(arg0);
    }

    private void updateLastModified() {
        lastModified = new Date();// now
    }

}
```

I'd recommend exposing a few constructors and adding a serial version id, but this gives you an idea to try.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default HashMap implementation this wouldn't be very easy: you'd have to keep a copy of the HashMap as the thread last saw it, and then do a deep comparison between the last-seen state and the current state. Further adding to the problem, that method wouldn't catch situations where the map changed and then changed back before the thread woke.

What I would do is subclass HashMap and add a `getLastModified` method. Override each of the modifier methods (`put`, `remove`, etc) and set the lastModified time, then call through to the `super` implementation. Then, your thread can simply check the modified time of your new `ChangeTrackingHashMap` to see if it has changed since it was last inspected.

Comment: he will still have to `synchronize` access to the map. The write isn't guaranteed to to *happen before* the read.

Comment: Oh let me be a bit clearer. The HashMap is a singleton, so it is not a new object

Comment: Yes, each of the methods would have to be synchronized if you wanted solid thread safety. If that's a concern I'd definitely recommend subclassing from ConcurrentHashMap however.

Comment: @Dan Smith if you're not able to change the map that's being used then you'd have to track the use of it, in this paradigm. Much harder.

Comment: @DanSmith - Making it `Singleton` will not change anything from `Synchronization` perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to completely change the concept. You actually want to perform periodic polling of your map. But how do you want to detect that the map has changed? Compare with what? With size? But if one entry was removed and other was added the size is not changed by map is.

Probably you want to compare the with clone of map that you created during the last iteration? But first, the map may be pretty large (lets say 100 million entries as an example). You have to iterate over the first map to be sure that all entries are in the second one and then iterate over second map to check that all keys are in the first one. Otherwise you will miss extra entries.

What do I suggest>? I suggest to wrap any map with wrapper that calls all methods of regular map except one: `put()`. This method calls put of your real map but also creates event that specific entry is changed. In this case you will get change notifications at real time instead of in 10 minutes.

public class NotifyableMap implements Map {
     private final Map map;
     public NotifyableMap(Map map) } {this.map = map;}

```
 public V put(K key, V value) {
     V oldValue = map.put(key, value);
     if (!value.equals(oldValue)) { // TODO: make this check null-safe
         // notify listeners here
     }
 }

 // all other methods are trivial
```

}